# How can I normalize/collapse paths or URLs in Python in OS independent way?

Tags: python, url, path, normalize

I tried to use `os.normpath` in order to convert `http://example.com/a/b/c/../` to `http://example.com/a/b/` but it doesn't work on Windows because it does convert the slash to backslash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how to do it

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.urljoin("ftp://domain.com/a/b/c/d/", "../..")
'ftp://domain.com/a/b/'
>>> urlparse.urljoin("ftp://domain.com/a/b/c/d/e.txt", "../..")
'ftp://domain.com/a/b/'
```

Remember that `urljoin` consider a path/directory all until the last `/` - after this is the filename, if any.

Also, do not add a leading `/` to the second parameter, otherwise you will not get the expected result.

`os.path` module is platform dependent but for file paths using only slashes but not-URLs you could use `posixpath,normpath`.

Comment: On the contrary: If the second parameter has a leading `/`, it will return `ftp://domain.com/../..`. Correcting.

Answer (score 8):

**Neither `urljoin` nor `posixpath.normpath` do the job properly**. `urljoin` forces you to join with something, and doesn't handle absolute paths or excessive `..`s correctly. `posixpath.normpath` collapses multiple slashes and removes trailing slashes, both of which are things URLs shouldn't do.

---

The following function resolves URLs completely, handling both `.`s and `..`s, in a correct way according to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4).

```
try:
    # Python 3
    from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urlunsplit
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    from urlparse import urlsplit, urlunsplit

def resolve_url(url):
    parts = list(urlsplit(url))
    segments = parts[2].split('/')
    segments = [segment + '/' for segment in segments[:-1]] + [segments[-1]]
    resolved = []
    for segment in segments:
        if segment in ('../', '..'):
            if resolved[1:]:
                resolved.pop()
        elif segment not in ('./', '.'):
            resolved.append(segment)
    parts[2] = ''.join(resolved)
    return urlunsplit(parts)
```

You can then call it on a complete URL as following.

```
>>> resolve_url("http://example.com/dir/../../thing/.")
'http://example.com/thing/'
```

For more information on the considerations that have to be made when resolving URLs, see [a similar answer I wrote earlier on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40536115/2280091).

Answer (score 2):

adopted from os module " - os.path is one of the modules posixpath, or ntpath", in your case explicitly using posixpath.

```
   >>> import posixpath
    >>> posixpath.normpath("/a/b/../c")
    '/a/c'
    >>>
```

Comment: `posixpath.normpath` does unhelpful things like removing trailing slashes and allowing double initial slash. Also replaces empty path with `.`.