# Python: How to resolve URLs containing '..'

Tags: python, url

I need to uniquely identify and store some URLs. The problem is that sometimes they come containing ".." like `http://somedomain.com/foo/bar/../../some/url` which basically is `http://somedomain.com/some/url` if I'm not wrong.

Is there a Python function or a tricky way to resolve this URLs ?

Comment: URL. I've put them like this because afterwords I compose them to the domain name, scheme and so on ...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131290/how-can-i-normalize-collapse-paths-or-urls-in-python-in-os-independent-way

Comment: @jleedev: that doesn't work for me. The numers of ".." can vary and are at different positions in the URL. And that is not even working as stated: urlparse.urljoin("ftp://domain.com/a/b/c/d/", "/../..") yells "ftp://domain.com/../.." on my machine ... :|

Comment: @Nicolae Changing it to `../..` works; I’ll correct it.

Comment: Firefox at least and, I would expect, all decent browsers, will never send requests of that style - they will interpret the ../ themselves. Personally I would ignore such URLs or send `400 Bad Request`.

Comment: @Chris: Those URL's are from a list of URLs and the code is used on a simple python script, I never said the code will be used on a web server

Comment: @Nicolae: what I'm saying is more or less just "`..` in a URL is bad".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There’s a simple solution using [`urllib.parse.urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin):

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urljoin
>>> urljoin('http://www.example.com/foo/bar/../../baz/bux/', '.')
'http://www.example.com/baz/bux/'
```

However, if there is no trailing slash (the last component is a file, not a directory), the last component will be removed.

This fix uses the urlparse function to extract the path, then use (the posixpath version of) [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) to normalize the components. Compensate for [a mysterious issue with trailing slashes](http://bugs.python.org/issue1707768), then join the URL back together. The following is `doctest`able:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import posixpath

def resolve_components(url):
    """
    >>> resolve_components('http://www.example.com/foo/bar/../../baz/bux/')
    'http://www.example.com/baz/bux/'
    >>> resolve_components('http://www.example.com/some/path/../file.ext')
    'http://www.example.com/some/file.ext'
    """
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    new_path = posixpath.normpath(parsed.path)
    if parsed.path.endswith('/'):
        # Compensate for issue1707768
        new_path += '/'
    cleaned = parsed._replace(path=new_path)
    return cleaned.geturl()
```

Comment: Super fancy! Works great. Thank a million!

Comment: It was too nice to be true :(. If the path is a file, after the join I will remain with the "folder" of the file: domain.com/some/path/file.ext will result in domain.com/some/path/ . I will find a workaround for this, because your solution is pretty awesome

Comment: @Nicolae I fix! `urljoin` appears to be clever but not ideal for the situation.

Comment: You should of left the old example too, and add this as an edit, because it was pure awesomeness and maybe it will help some other poor soul

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work if there are too many `..` in the URL. e.g. `urljoin('http://x.com/../index.html','.')` -> `'http://x.com/../'` instead of the correct `'http://x.com/index.html'`.

Comment: `urljoin` doesn't work if the second component is absolute, either, sadly. For example, `urljoin("http://example.com/blah.html", "./././whoa.html")` *does* remove the dots, while `urljoin("http://example.com/blah.html", "/./././whoa.html")` doesn't.

Comment: Oh, also, `posixpath.normpath` normalizes several slashes (e.g. `"//////`) to one single slash. According to both RFC and browser implementations, that should not happen.

Answer (score 4):

Those are file paths.  Look at [os.path.normpath](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.normpath('/foo/bar/../../some/url')
'/some/url'
```

**EDIT:**

If this is on Windows, your input path will use backslashes instead of slashes.  In this case, you still need `os.path.normpath` to get rid of the `..` patterns (and `//` and `/./` and whatever else is redundant), then convert the backslashes to forward slashes:

```
def fix_path_for_URL(path):
    result = os.path.normpath(path)
    if os.sep == '\\':
        result = result.replace('\\', '/')
    return result
```

**EDIT 2:**

If you want to normalize URLs, do it (before you strip off the method and such) with [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) module, as shown in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131290/how-can-i-normalize-collapse-paths-or-urls-in-python-in-os-independent-way).

***EDIT 3:***

It seems that `urljoin` doesn't normalize the base path it's given:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.urljoin('http://somedomain.com/foo/bar/../../some/url', '')
'http://somedomain.com/foo/bar/../../some/url'
```

`normpath` by itself doesn't quite cut it either:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.normpath('http://somedomain.com/foo/bar/../../some/url')
'http:/somedomain.com/some/url'
```

Note the initial double slash got eaten.

So we have to make them join forces:

```
def fix_URL(urlstring):
    parts = list(urlparse.urlparse(urlstring))
    parts[2] = os.path.normpath(parts[2].replace('/', os.sep)).replace(os.sep, '/')
    return urlparse.urlunparse(parts)
```

Usage:

```
>>> fix_URL('http://somedomain.com/foo/bar/../../some/url')
'http://somedomain.com/some/url'
```

Comment: Be warned that “On Windows, it converts forward slashes to backward slashes.”

Comment: This is almost perfect, but maybe I was not specific enough in my question (I've edited to reflect this more properly): those ARE URLs, I've just omitted the domain name and schema.

Comment: this converts path `/foo/bar/../../some/url'` to `/some/url` in python 3 for me on mac..

Answer (score 3):

**`urljoin` won't work**, as it only resolves dot segments if the second argument isn't absolute(!?) or empty. Not only that, it doesn't handle excessive `..`s properly according to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4) (they should be removed; `urljoin` doesn't do so). **`posixpath.normpath` can't be used either** (much less `os.path.normpath)`, since it resolves multiple slashes in a row to only one (e.g. `/////` becomes `/`), which is incorrect behavior for URLs.

---

The following short function resolves any URL path string correctly. It **shouldn't be used with relative paths**, however, since additional decisions about its behavior would then need to be made (Raise an error on excessive `..`s? Remove `.` in the beginning? Leave them both?) - instead, join URLs before resolving if you know you might handle relative paths. Without further ado:

```
def resolve_url_path(path):
    segments = path.split('/')
    segments = [segment + '/' for segment in segments[:-1]] + [segments[-1]]
    resolved = []
    for segment in segments:
        if segment in ('../', '..'):
            if resolved[1:]:
                resolved.pop()
        elif segment not in ('./', '.'):
            resolved.append(segment)
    return ''.join(resolved)
```

This handles trailing dot segments (that is, without a trailing slash) *and* consecutive slashes correctly. To resolve an entire URL, you can then use the following wrapper (or just inline the path resolution function into it).

```
try:
    # Python 3
    from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urlunsplit
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    from urlparse import urlsplit, urlunsplit

def resolve_url(url):
    parts = list(urlsplit(url))
    parts[2] = resolve_url_path(parts[2])
    return urlunsplit(parts)
```

---

You can then call it like this:

```
>>> resolve_url('http://example.com/../thing///wrong/../multiple-slashes-yeah/.')
'http://example.com/thing///multiple-slashes-yeah/'
```

Correct URL resolution has more than a few pitfalls, it turns out!

Comment: “it doesn't handle excessive `..`s properly” — it does for me on Python 3.5 (but not 2.7)

Comment: ...nor on 3.4 :(

Comment: Can you elaborate why `/////` becoming `/` is incorrect behavior for URLs? I skimmed through the entire [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3) to find keyword `//`, but could not find anything they suggest adjacent slashes in path such as `//` would be meaningful.

Comment: @RayLuo Take a look at [Section 3.3: Path](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3). In the ABNF description of `path-absolute`, it specifies it can simply contain a `segment`, which is later defined as `*pchar`. That asterisk means it can contain any number of `pchar`s, including 0. Therefore, according to the standard, the path `///` is 3 separate, non-collapsible 0-length segments.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to comment on the `resolveComponents` function in the top response.

Notice that if your path is `/`, the code will add another one which can be problematic.
I therefore changed the `IF` condition to:

```
if parsed.path.endswith( '/' ) and parsed.path != '/':
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.2) this should happen as part of "relative resolution" process. So answer could be `urlparse.urljoin(url, '')`. But due to bug `urlparse.urljoin` does not remove dot segments when second argument is empty url. You can use [yurl](https://github.com/homm/yurl) — alternative url manipulation library. It do this right:

```
>>> import yurl
>>> print yurl.URL('http://somedomain.com/foo/bar/../../some/url') + yurl.URL()
http://somedomain.com/some/url
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import urlparse
import posixpath

parsed = list(urlparse.urlparse(url))
parsed[2] = posixpath.normpath(posixpath.join(parsed[2], rel_path))
proper_url = urlparse.urlunparse(parsed)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to the base URL, and then you can use `urljoin` from `urllib.parse`

example :

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
    
def resolve_urls( urls, site):
    for url in urls:
        print(urljoin(site, url))
    return

urls= ["/aboutMytest", "#", "/terms-of-use", "https://www.example.com/Admission"]

resolve_urls(urls,'https://example.com/')
```

output :

```
https://example.com/aboutMytest
https://example.com/
https://example.com/terms-of-use
https://www.example.com/Admission
```