# Python urljoin not removing superflous dots

Tags: python, url

I'm using urljoin to get the absolute URL of links of a page.  For the most part it does a good job at things like resolving relative links, but I notice that for some reason it does not remove superflous dots in some cases.  For example:

```
>>> urljoin("http://x.com","http://x.com/../../X",False)
'http://x.com/../../X'
>>> urljoin("http://x.com","http://x.com/./../X",False)
'http://x.com/./../X'
```

If I give such an URL to a web browser, it corrects it fine, but if I try to use Python's urlopen() it throws an exception (urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request).

Is this expected behavior?  Is there some other Python function that correctly removes these dots that I should be using instead, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use an absolute `base` and a relative `url`.
If you call it like this, it removes the dots:

```
urljoin("http://x.com/a/b/page.html","../../index.html",False)
# result: 'http://x.com/index.html'

urljoin("http://x.com/a/b/page.html","./index.html",False)
# result: 'http://x.com/a/b/index.html'
```

I found a way to normalize a url in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317242/python-how-to-resolve-urls-containing). Example:

```
urljoin('http://www.example.com/foo/bar/../../baz/bux/', '.')
# result: 'http://www.example.com/baz/bux/'
```

I think the invalid url handling (too much `..`) can only be handled "manually", like this:

```
def remove_extra_dots(url):
    parsed = list(urlparse(url))
    dirs = []
    for name in parsed[2].split("/"):
        if name == "..":
            if len(dirs) > 1:
                dirs.pop()
        else:
            dirs.append(name)
    parsed[2] = "/".join(dirs)
    return urlunparse(parsed)
```

This will eliminate all `..`s from the url, even the invalid ones. Examples:

```
"http://x.com/a/b/c/../../X"  #->  http://x.com/a/X
"http://x.com/a/b/../../X"    #->  http://x.com/X
"http://x.com/../../X"        #->  http://x.com/X
```

Comment: ok, so maybe use urlparse to extract the path part to pass as the second parameter?

Comment: hmm nope, that won't work either, because urlparse().path has a leading '/' in front of it in such cases.

Comment: also doesn't seem to work if there are too many `..`, e.g. `urljoin("http://x.com/a/b/page.html","../../../index.html",False)` -> `'http://x.com/../index.html'`

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your situation. Where is the `"http://x.com/../../X"` value coming from in your example?

Comment: i'm scraping a set of pages (for migration) and these occasionally occur in the HREF of an anchor here and there.

Comment: I see. I added another idea to my answer.

Comment: nice update, but unfortunately that still doesn't work if there are too many `..` in the URL. e.g. `urljoin('http://x.com/../index.html','.')` -> `'http://x.com/../'`.

Comment: As the linked answer states: this only works for directory urls, not for files. But I thought it might help. Btw, since that url is invalid, what would be your expected result?

Comment: If I put the URL into a browser, it modifies it to `http://x.com/index.html`.  But, it is starting to look like the solution in this case is to simply find and fix all the offending links.

Comment: I added my last resort idea to my answer. It's not pretty, but still better than hand fixing all the bad links.

Comment: @Michael Some response would have been nice.

Comment: thanks, i'll accept since that looks like it should work.  unfortunately, by that time i had (in parallel) already managed to manually all 60 or so bad links.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a bug! According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4), those superfluous `..` segments should be removed. No Python standard library function I've been able to find really does the job correctly.

---

The existing answer is slightly incorrect in a couple of ways, sadly. URL resolution is a bit more complicated than one might expect.

In addition to the shortcomings of `urljoin` mentioned there (it doesn't resolve URLs when joining an absolute path, and it doesn't handle excessive `..`s), joining an URL with `.` will remove the last segment. For example, `urljoin('http://example.com/dir/./wrong/../file.txt', '.')` will result in `'http://example.com/dir/'`, removing the file and thus making you have to add it back in. Also, `urljoin('http://example.com/dir/..', '.')` results in `'http://example.com/dir/'`, which is just simply wrong for your case.

Not only that, the `remove_extra_dots` function provided actually has a bug in it. If the URL ends in a trailing dot segment (which the last bug in the previous paragraph renders impossible, but if it was somehow fixed), a trailing slash *won't* be added. Consider `remove_extra_dots('http://example.com/..')`. This should result in `'http://example.com/'`, but actually results in `'http://example.com'` (note the missing slash). It's a small difference, but a lot of sites do redirects on receiving missing slashes, so you might get unexpected results.

---

The following function completely resolves URLs - that is, both `.`s and `..`s - following RFC 3986. Without having to rely on `urljoin`, too!

```
try:
    # Python 3
    from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urlunsplit
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    from urlparse import urlsplit, urlunsplit

def resolve_url(url):
    parts = list(urlsplit(url))
    segments = parts[2].split('/')
    segments = [segment + '/' for segment in segments[:-1]] + [segments[-1]]
    resolved = []
    for segment in segments:
        if segment in ('../', '..'):
            if resolved[1:]:
                resolved.pop()
        elif segment not in ('./', '.'):
            resolved.append(segment)
    parts[2] = ''.join(resolved)
    return urlunsplit(parts)
```

You can then call it when you have your complete URL (in your case, after joining) as following.

```
>>> resolve_url("http://example.com/dir/../../thing/.")
'http://example.com/thing/'
```

For more information on what works/doesn't work, see [a similar answer I wrote on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40536115/2280091).