# How do I get urljoin to work as expected in Python?

Tags: python, url, urlparse

Let's say I have the following URLs:

```
url = https://www.example.com/thing1/thing2/thing3
next_thing = thing4
```

and I want the following URL:

```
https://www.example.com/thing1/thing2/thing3/thing4
```

When I try

```
>>> urlparse.urljoin(url,next_thing)
```

I get the following result:

```
https://www.example.com/thing1/thing2/thing4
```

Why is `thing3` being cut out? And how do I resolve that? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trailing slash is missing in the URL, append it to make `thing3` a "directory":

```
>>> from urlparse import urljoin
>>> url = "https://www.example.com/thing1/thing2/thing3"

>>> urljoin(url, "thing4")
'https://www.example.com/thing1/thing2/thing4'
>>> urljoin(url + "/", "thing4")
'https://www.example.com/thing1/thing2/thing3/thing4'
```

Comment: Interesting! Thank you @alecxe! I will try this and like/accept your answer if it works. In the mean time, do you know why the trailing slash makes a difference?

Comment: @codycrossley without a slash `thing3` is a considered "filename", some explanation is available here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4317446/771848. Glad it helped.

Comment: ahhh, makes sense! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure but think this might be what you're looking for.

```
url = 'https://www.example.com/thing1/thing2/thing3'
next_thing = 'thing4'
test = url + next_thing
print(test)
```

Comes out with:

```
https://www.example.com/thing1/thing2/thing3/thing4
```

Comment: I agree that this will work, and it's what I was using prior, but I am trying to stick to the urlparse.urljoin method for now. Thank you so much for your feedback!

Comment: Sorry didn't quite realise that!

Comment: No worries! =] I really do appreciate your feedback though!

Comment: This will actually result in `https://www.example.com/thing1/thing2/thing3thing4`, note the missing slash between `thing3` and `thing4`.