# Python request can't get image from url

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, request

i got a URL that content a image and i wish to download it using python3 requests get:

```
import requests
imageURL = "http://www.360mop.com/../upload/tw_header/2015063011211042.jpg"
response = requests.get(imageURL)

print(response)
<Response [400]>
```

is there a way to ignore the '../' path? or i have to remove it manually? or there is a better way to get image form a URL?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? What do you mean by, "ignore the  ../ path". Does the "http://www.360mop.com/upload/tw_header/2015063011211042.jpg" contain your image?

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317242/python-how-to-resolve-urls-containing

Comment: You need to get the full URL. The "/../" has probably been added to shorten it. After you read the data, write it into a file. Its as simple as that.

Comment: "/../" can't be a shorten URL in this cause, http://www.360mop.com/ is already a root directory, if you use browser visit "http://www.360mop.com/../upload/tw_header/2015063011211042.jpg", it will auto remove "../", but python requests will not fix it for you

Comment: thank you alecxe, that helps alot

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the relative path with `replace` will works:

```
import requests
root = 'http://www.360mop.com/'
other = "../upload/tw_header/2015063011211042.jpg".replace('../', '')
imageURL = root + other
response = requests.get(imageURL)
print response

#<Response [200]>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my way to solve the problem in Python3:

```
import os
from urllib.request import urlparse

def UrlResolve(url):
    p = urlparse(url)
    clear_url = p.scheme + "://" + p.netloc + os.path.normpath(p.path)
    return clear_url
```