# Canonicalize / normalize a URL?

Tags: url, python-3.x, normalization

I am searching for a library function to normalize a URL in Python, that is to remove "./" or "../" parts in the path, or add a default port or escape special characters and so on. The result should be a string that is unique for two URLs pointing to the same web page. For example `http://google.com` and `http://google.com:80/a/../` shall return the same result.

I would prefer Python 3 and already looked through the `urllib` module. It offers functions to split URLs but nothing to canonicalize them. Java has the `URI.normalize()` function that does a similar thing (though it does not consider the default port 80 equal to no given port), but is there something like this is python?

Comment: As a side note, a resource such as `http://google.com/` is not the same than `http://google.com:80/a/../`. That is, if `/a` does not exist, then the second path will fail. By "canonicalizing" it, you lose that special case and end up with a valid URI when you started with an invalid one...

Comment: that is not correct, not in browsers anyway. you can write http://google.com:80/a/../ even if a does not exist, and it will go to http://google.com:80/.
That is because the browser does the initial parsing before it is sent to the server. At the server side, different servers behave in different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [good start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10587428/1018226), I composed a method that fits most of the cases commonly found in the web.

```
def urlnorm(base, link=''):
  '''Normalizes an URL or a link relative to a base url. URLs that point to the same resource will return the same string.'''
  new = urlparse(urljoin(base, url).lower())
  return urlunsplit((
    new.scheme,
    (new.port == None) and (new.hostname + ":80") or new.netloc,
    new.path,
    new.query,
    ''))
```

Comment: What about https ?

Answer (score 4):

This is what I use and it's worked so far. You can get urlnorm from pip.

Notice that I sort the query parameters. I've found this to be essential.

```
from urlparse import urlsplit, urlunsplit, parse_qsl
from urllib import urlencode
import urlnorm

def canonizeurl(url):
    split = urlsplit(urlnorm.norm(url))
    path = split[2].split(' ')[0]

    while path.startswith('/..'):
        path = path[3:]

    while path.endswith('%20'):
        path = path[:-3]

    qs = urlencode(sorted(parse_qsl(split.query)))
    return urlunsplit((split.scheme, split.netloc, path, qs, ''))
```

Comment: nice, removes invalid parent directories

Comment: You need to replace `split[2].split(' ')[0]` with `urllib.parse.quote(split[2])` - in some cases, having spaces in a URL is completely normal, and in fact required.
Also, urlnorm is py2k only

Comment: Also, you're discarding the fragment, which can actually be a required URL component, in some unusual cases. Yes, there are a non-zero number of webpages where `blah.com/#wat` is a completely different page then `blah.com/`. It's generally done with javascript, and is an enormous PITA, but it exists.

Comment: @FakeName wrote: "having spaces in a URL is completely normal, and in fact required".  No, that is absolutely INCORRECT.  Spaces are NEVER allowed in a URL.  Read the spec: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396  Some browsers misleadingly display spaces, but in fact they are percent-encoded.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
In [1]: from urllib.parse import urljoin

In [2]: urljoin('http://example.com/a/b/c/../', '.')
Out[2]: 'http://example.com/a/b/'
```

Inspired by answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131290/how-can-i-normalize-collapse-paths-or-urls-in-python-in-os-independent-way). It doesn't normalize ports, but it should be simple to whip up a function that does.

Comment: I don't have `urllib.parse`, but I do have `urlparse`.

Comment: `urllib.parse` is the Python 3 location - the original question was asked about Py 3.

Comment: This fails pretty badly on anything that does not end in '/'

Comment: This removes the last component, regardless. That's not normalisation! E.g. `http://example.com/a/../b/c` becomes `http://example.com/b/`, dropping the `c` component.

Answer (score 2):

### Old (deprecated) answer

The *[no longer maintained]* [urltools](https://github.com/erazor85/urltools) module normalizes multiple slashes, `.` and `..` components without messing up the double slash in `http://`.

Once you do <s>`pip install urltools`</s> *(this does not work anymore as the author renamed the repo)* the usage is as follows:

```python
print urltools.normalize('http://example.com:80/a////b/../c')
>>> 'http://example.com/a/c'
```

While the module is not pip-installable anymore it is [a single file](https://github.com/erazor85/urltools/blob/master/urltools/urltools.py) so you can re-use bits of it.

### Updated answer for Python3

For Python3 consider using [`urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) from the [`urllib.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) module.

```py
from urllib.parse import urljoin

urljoin('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584861/', '../dinsdale')
# Out[17]: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/dinsdale'
```

Comment: urltools seems to have left the planet. No github, no pypi, no cached copy anywhere. If someone knows what happened, please let me know.

Comment: @GaneshKathiresan: looks like the author decided to rename the repo; updated

Answer (score 1):

There is now a library dedicated this exact problem [url-normalize](https://pypi.org/project/url-normalize)

It does more than just normalising the path as per the docs:

> URI Normalization function:
>
> 1. Take care of IDN domains.
> 2. Always provide the URI scheme in lowercase characters.
> 3. Always provide the host, if any, in lowercase characters.
> 4. Only perform percent-encoding where it is essential.
> 5. Always use uppercase A-through-F characters when percent-encoding.
> 6. Prevent dot-segments appearing in non-relative URI paths.
> 7. For schemes that define a default authority, use an empty authority if the default is desired.
> 8. For schemes that define an empty path to be equivalent to a path of "/", use "/".
> 9. For schemes that define a port, use an empty port if the default is desired
> 10. All portions of the URI must be utf-8 encoded NFC from Unicode strings

Here is an example:

```
from url_normalize import url_normalize

url = 'http://google.com:80/a/../'
print(url_normalize(url))
```

Which gives:

```
http://google.com/
```

Comment: Nice! The only thing that does not work well is when not providing a protocol, it returns HTTPS instead of HTTP. 
example.com turns to "https:////example.com"

Comment: @GilCohen , https is the recommended practice these days, so that behavior is probably intentional.  See [W3C statement](https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/web-https) and [US government policy](https://https.cio.gov/guide/), for example.

Comment: In theory you might be correct, but in practice when the protocol is not stated, browsers try HTTP first.

Answer (score 0):

I used @Antony's answer above and used the [url-normalize](https://pypi.org/project/url-normalize) library, but it has one bug that is not currently fixed: When a URL is sent without a scheme, is accidentally sets it to HTTPS. I wrote a function that wraps and fixes it by setting it to HTTP instead:

```
from url_normalize import url_normalize
from urllib.parse import urlparse


def parse_url(url):
    return_val = url_normalize(url)
    wrong_default_prefix = "https://"
    new_default_prefix = "http://"
    # If the URL came with no scheme and the normalize function mistakenly 
    # set it to the HTTPS protocol, then fix it and set it to HTTP
    if urlparse(url).scheme.strip() == '' and return_val.startswith(wrong_default_prefix):
        return_val = new_default_prefix + return_val[len(wrong_default_prefix):]
    return return_val
```

Comment: Did the author of that library say it was a mistake?  It looks intentional to me, since https should be preferred over http for security.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't as this is not how browsers behave.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option that doesn't require third party libraries from Pip, nor abuse of the `urljoin`: use [`posixpath.normpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) on only the path portion of your URL.

Here's an example from an interactive session:

```py
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> import posixpath
>>> 
>>> u = 'http://google.com/a/../b'
>>> parsed = urllib.parse.urlparse(u)
>>> normalized = posixpath.normpath(parsed.path)
>>> r = parsed._replace(path=normalized)
>>> r.geturl()
'http://google.com/b'
```

Note that we use `posixpath` instead of `os.path`; this will make it work on Windows, too.