# Python - Shortest way to format a string to an url

Tags: python, replace, slug

I'm involved in a web project. I have to choose the best ways to represent the code, so that other people can read it without problems/headaches/whatever.

The "problem" I've tackled now is to show a nice formatted url (will be taken from a "title" string).

So, let's suppose we have a title, fetched from the form:

```
title = request.form['title'] # 'Hello World, Hello Cat! Hello?'
```

then we need a function to format it for inclusion in the url (it needs to become 'hello_world_hello_cat_hello'), so for the moment I'm using this one which I think sucks for readability:

```
str.replace(title, ' ', '-').str.replace(title, '!', '').str.replace(title, '?', '').str.replace(string, ',' '').lower()
```

What would be a good way to compact it? Is there already a function for doing what I'm doing?

I'd also like to know which characters/symbols I should strip from the url.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Canonize / normalize an URL in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584861/canonize-normalize-an-url-in-python)

Comment: @aspect_mkn8rd no its not

Comment: See [String slugification in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574042/string-slugification-in-python).

Comment: @heinst ah -( I'm very sorry then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
re.sub(r'!|\?|,', '', text)
```

This will remove ! ? and , from the string.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html?highlight=urlencode#urllib.urlencode) which is *the* way for url-encode strings in Python.

If otherwise you want a personalized encoding as your expected output and all you want to do is leave the words in the final string you can use the [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html?highlight=re.findall#re.findall) function to grab them and later join them with and underscore:

```
>>>s = 'Hello World, Hello Cat! Hello?'
>>>'_'.join(re.findall(r'\w+',s)).lower()
'hello_world_hello_cat_hello'
```

What this does is:

```
g = re.findall(r'\w+',s) # ['Hello', 'World', 'Hello', 'Cat', 'Hello']
s1 = '_'.join(g) # 'Hello_World_Hello_Cat_Hello'
s1.lower() # 'hello_world_hello_cat_hello'
```

This technique also works well with numbers in the string:

```
>>>s = 'Hello World, Hello Cat! H123ello? 123'
>>>'_'.join(re.findall(r'\w+',s)).lower()
'hello_world_hello_cat_h123ello_123'
```

Another way which I think should be faster is to actually replace non alphanumeric chars. This can be accomplished with [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html?highlight=re.findall#re.sub) by grabbing all the non alphanumerics toghether and replace them with `_` like this:

```
>>>re.sub(r'\W+','_',s).lower()
'hello_world_hello_cat_h123ello_123'
```

Well... not really, speed tests:

```
$python -mtimeit -s "import re" -s "s='Hello World, Hello Cat! Hello?'" "'_'.join(re.findall(r'\w+',s)).lower()"
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.08 usec per loop


$python -mtimeit -s "import re" -s "s='Hello World, Hello Cat! Hello?'" "re.sub(r'\W+','_',s).lower()"
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.55 usec per loop
```

Comment: wow that's really smart! Much more concise than my answer. I'd be interested in speed, but honestly this DOES NOT appear to be a function that will limit performance so it's definitely early optimization to be worried about that

Comment: @AdamSmith `translate` is really fast and I really try to avoid regular expressions as much as I can but this task seemed to be really simple using them :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `urlencode()` from the `urllib` module in python2 or `urllib.parse` module in python3.

This will work assuming you're trying to use the text in the query string of your URL.

```
title = {'title': 'Hello World, Hello Cat! Hello?'} # or get it programmatically as you did
encoded = urllib.urlencode(title)
print encoded # title=Hello+World%2C+Hello+Cat%21+Hello%3F
```

Comment: As per OP: "so that other people can read it without problems/headaches/whatever." I've got a headache just looking at `%2C` :) Otherwise a stellar solution, and one I would use myself, so still +1

Comment: @AdamSmith I thought OP was referring to code readability, not the url, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @jshanley upon a second read, you might be right. Regardless, this is the BEST solution :)

Comment: I was also confused by the OP's readability comment and the output example. This is, of course _the_ way for url encode strings in Python :)

Answer (score 3):

So I've been playing with all your answer's solutions and here's what I've come up with.

*note: These "benchmarks" are not to be taken too seriously, as I didn't go through all the possible plans, but it's a good way to have a fast broad view.*

**re.findall()**

```
def findall():
  string = 'Hello World, Hello Cat! Hello?'
  return  '_'.join(re.findall(r'\w+',string)).lower()
```

*real=0.019s, user=0.012s, sys=0.004s, rough=0.016s*

**re.sub()**

```
def sub():
  string = 'Hello World, Hello Cat! Hello?'
  return re.sub(r'\W+','_',string).lower()
```

*real=0.020s, user=0.016s, sys=0.004s, rough=0.020s*

**slugify()**

```
def slug():
  string = 'Hello World, Hello Cat! Hello?'
  return slugify(string)
```

*real=0.031s, user=0.024s, sys=0.004s, rough=0.028s*

**urllib.urlencode()**

```
def urlenc():
  string = {'title': 'Hello World, Hello Cat! Hello?'}
  return urllib.urlencode(string)
```

*real=0.036s, user=0.024s, sys=0.008s, rough=0.032s*

As you can see, the fastest is **re.findall()**, the slowest **urllib.urlencode()** and in the middle there's **slugify()** which is also the shortest/cleanest of them all (altough not the fastest).

What I've chosen for now is **Slugify**, the lucky cat in between the bulldogs.

Answer (score 0):

sure you can do this:

```
import string

uppers = string.ascii_uppercase # ABC...Z
lowers = string.ascii_lowercase # abc...z
removals = ''.join([ch for ch in string.punctuation if ch != '_'])

transtable = str.maketrans(uppers+" ",lowers+"_",removals)
title = "Hello World, Hello Cat! Hello?"
title.translate(transtable)
```

You could also do a list comp and `''.join` it.

```
whitelist = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + " "

newtitle = ''.join('_' if ch == ' ' else ch.lower() for ch in title if ch in
             whitelist)
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean you could split it up into multiple statements:

```
str = str.replace(title, ' ', '-')
str = str.replace(title, '!', '')
str = str.replace(title, '?', '')
str = str.replace(string, ',' '')
str = str.lower()
```

This will make for better readability.